# Do we need to pass Base_URI when we use URI_Storage in solidity openzeppelin

Tags: solidity, web3js, openzeppelin

I want to make a mintable NFT. where NFTs can be added after deployment of smart contract.
do i need to give base URI, when i use URI storage.
I'm
using openzeppelin wizard to make smart contract (https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/wizard)

[image]

Comment: No, you could override tokenURI and define it any way you like, for example storing independent RUI for each tokenId.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to. You can check out the logic of `ERC721URIStorage` below, it said that by default it will use your defined uri if no base_uri is defined, otherwise it will use <base_uri> + <defined_uri>. Or you can override the tokenURI function and implement your own logic.

```
/**
     * @dev See {IERC721Metadata-tokenURI}.
     */
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI query for nonexistent token");

        string memory _tokenURI = _tokenURIs[tokenId];
        string memory base = _baseURI();

        // If there is no base URI, return the token URI.
        if (bytes(base).length == 0) {
            return _tokenURI;
        }
        // If both are set, concatenate the baseURI and tokenURI (via abi.encodePacked).
        if (bytes(_tokenURI).length > 0) {
            return string(abi.encodePacked(base, _tokenURI));
        }

        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }
```